# Chart.js - change starting position of scale/line

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

So I'm using Chart.js to plot a graph on my web app,
What I'm trying to achieve is to control the starting point of the graph itself, so I could control where the scales are located

This is what I have so far:

[image]

Eventually, I'm trying to make the scale appear at the center of each "stripe".
I've seen in the documentation that you can extend scales and charts to customize it to your own needs but I tried fiddling with it with no success regarding what I need.

This is an example of what I'm trying to achieve:

[image]

Code:

```
var type = 'line';
var daysArray = new Array(30).join().split(',').map(function (item, index) { ++index; return (index % 5 == 0 || index == 1) ? index : '' })
var data = {
    labels: this.daysArray,
    datasets: [{
        borderColor: "#707bbb",
        showLine: false,
        fill: false,
        pointBackgroundColor: "#707bbb",
        pointRadius: 3,
        data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 20, 32, 65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 20, 32]
    },
        {
            borderColor: "#2972c5",
            borderWidth: 1,
            fill: false,
            pointRadius: 0,
            data: [102, 42, 36, 98, 15, 15, 19, 65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 20, 32]
        }
    ]
};

var options = {
    bezierCurve: false,
    responsive: true,
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    display: false,
    scales: {
        yAxes: [{
            display: false
        }],
        xAxes: [{
            gridLines: {
                drawOnChartArea: true,
                drawBorder: false
            },
            ticks: {
                fontStyle: "normal",
                maxRotation: 0,
                labelOffset: 1
            }
        }]
    },
    legend: {
        display: false
    }
};

Chart.pluginService.register({
      beforeDatasetsDraw: function (chart, easing) {
        if (chart.chartArea) {

          var noOfLabels = chart.chart.config.data.labels.length;
          var helpers = Chart.helpers;
          var ctx = chart.chart.ctx;
          //
          ctx.save();
          var chartArea = chart.chartArea;
          var chartWidth = chartArea.right - chartArea.left;
          var chartHeight = Math.abs(chartArea.top - chartArea.bottom);

          var stripWidth = chartWidth / noOfLabels;
          var pattern = document.createElement('canvas');
          pattern.width = stripWidth * 2;
          pattern.height = chartHeight;
          var pctx = pattern.getContext('2d');

          pctx.fillStyle = "#f0f2f5";
          pctx.fillRect(0, 0, stripWidth, chartHeight);
          pctx.fillStyle = "#ffffff";
          pctx.fillRect(stripWidth, 0, stripWidth, chartHeight);

          var ptr = ctx.createPattern(pattern, "repeat");
          ctx.fillStyle = ptr;

          ctx.fillRect(chartArea.left, chartArea.top, chartArea.right - chartArea.left, chartArea.bottom - chartArea.top);
          ctx.restore();
          ctx.save();
        }


      },


    });

    Chart.scaleService.getScaleConstructor("category").extend({
      margins: {
        left: 100
      },
      paddingLeft: 300
    });

    this.chart = new Chart(document.querySelector('canvas'), {
      type: type,
      data: data,
      options: options
    });
```

The code is a bit messy because I tried playing with some options and thought I would leave it just there

Anyone has an idea what to do?

Comment: Have you looked into the annotations plugin ? Here's an example: [Codepen: Annotations Chart.js](http://codepen.io/k3no/pen/yaGGGW)

Comment: Could you add a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with details so that we can have a base to work on and help you ?

Comment: @Tektiv, added code!